How can I edit this python script to automatically apply the excel formula to show the results when opened?
I have a spreadsheet that is opened via the package openpyxl and I want to apply a specific formula to every cell in row 14 "N" down to the bottom of my current table but make the formula results apply on open of the file because at the moment it populates the cells as required however I have to double click on the cell and hit enter to make the results appear on every row.
# Load the workbook
workbook = load_workbook(new_filepath)

# Select the sheet 'Inc Multiple Classifications'
sheet = workbook['Inc Multiple Classifications']



# Assuming Table14 starts at cell A1 (adjust as per your actual table location)
start_row = 2
start_col = 14

# Determine the dimensions of the table (adjust based on your table's size)
num_rows = lengthofBCCFile  # Number of rows in Table14
num_cols = 1  # Number of columns in Table14

# Iterate through each cell in the table and apply the formula
for row in range(start_row, start_row + num_rows):
    for col in range(start_col, start_col + num_cols):
        cell = sheet.cell(row=row, column=col)
        # Build the formula string
        formula = f'=TRIM(IFERROR(LET(p, UPPER(SUBSTITUTE(K{row}, " ", "")), n, LEN(p),     LEFT(p, n-3)&" "&RIGHT(p, 3)), ""))'
        # Set the formula to the cell
        cell.value = formula

# Save the workbook
workbook.save(new_filepath)
workbook.close()

This is what the results returned when the file is opened which shows the formula in the cells of column N however no result until I double click on the cell and press enter.


You can change your calculation mode to "Automatic" in excel. (Formulas -> Calculation Options -> Automatic)

is it possible to set this mode via python as the spreadsheet is originally created via python further up my code?

I believe xlwings can do that: https://github.com/xlwings/xlwings/issues/158, not sure about openpyxl.

Setting the Workbook Calculation' Mode in Openpyxl?, wb.calculation.calcMode will show the current state e.g. print(wb.calculation.calcMode) and also set it, e.g. wb.calculation.calcMode = 'auto'

If the suggested option doesn't work, you are better off using Xlwings to add the formulas anyway if that is an option (i.e. Excel is available). This module will ensure the formulas are evaluated and will be saved with the workbook. btw workbook.close() will do nothing in your code

It's worth knowing that what you SEE in the formula is not always what Excel stores in the worksheet file so you should prepared to look at that.

The Excel function LET was introduced after publishing the Office Open XML file system in 2007. Thus not all spreadsheet applications will support this function. To mark this, such functions are prefixed by _xlfn in file storage.
If the Excel version not supports this function, then the _xlfn prefix get visible in formula string in Excel's GUI too and results in #NAME? error.
If the Excel version supports this function, then the _xlfn prefix is not visible in formula string in Excel's GUI and the function gets evaluated.
In your case the Excel version supports this function LET but it is not marked by _xlfn prefix in file storage. Excel marks this problem with @ in formula string in GUI because it looks like if that LET was authored in an older version of Excel.
Since OpenPyXL directly writes into file storage that prefix must be set in formula string. Wrong is formula = "...LET(...". Correct is formula = "..._xlfn.LET(...".
Furthermore lambda arguments are prefixed with _xlpm in in file storage.
Thus your correct formula string will be
formula = f'=TRIM(IFERROR(_xlfn.LET(_xlpm.p, UPPER(SUBSTITUTE(K{row}, " ", "")), _xlpm.n, LEN(_xlpm.p), LEFT(_xlpm.p, _xlpm.n-3)&" "&RIGHT(_xlpm.p, 3)), ""))'

Complete example to show it works:
from openpyxl import Workbook
workbook  = Workbook()

sheet = workbook .active
sheet['K1'] = "Col K"
sheet['N1'] = "Formula"
data = [{'K':"abcdefg"}, {'K':"abcdefgh"}, {'K':"abcdefghi"}, {'K':"abcdefghij"}]
for row in data:
    sheet.append(row)

start_row = 2
start_col = 14

num_rows = len(data)
num_cols = 1 

for row in range(start_row, start_row + num_rows):
    for col in range(start_col, start_col + num_cols):
        cell = sheet.cell(row=row, column=col)
        # Build the formula string
        formula = f'=TRIM(IFERROR(_xlfn.LET(_xlpm.p, UPPER(SUBSTITUTE(K{row}, " ", "")), _xlpm.n, LEN(_xlpm.p), LEFT(_xlpm.p, _xlpm.n-3)&" "&RIGHT(_xlpm.p, 3)), ""))'
        # Set the formula to the cell
        cell.value = formula

workbook.save('excelResult.xlsx')


Aren't the curly brackets and the @ symbol indications of some additional stuff that Excel is doing?

@Charlie Clark: Tried elaborating the reason for the @ little bit more. But what curly brackets you are talking about?

@ converts 1x1 array into a string in Excel. So in this OP, omitting _xlfn will still work. (Though maybe for the wrong reason)

wb.calculation.calcMode = 'auto' definitely works.
I tried simple code:
Setting calculation mode to "Manual"
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.active
ws["A1"] = "=SUM(1, 1)"

wb.calculation.calcMode = 'manual'
wb.save('test.xlsx')

I got this: (that is, =SUM(1, 1) is not evaluated".

But if I set calculation mode to "auto":
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.active
ws["A1"] = "=SUM(1, 1)"

wb.calculation.calcMode = 'auto'
wb.save('test.xlsx')

I got below:


If the mode is set to "auto", formula will be evaluated upon opening the file. if it is set to "manual", formula will not be evaluated upon opening the file.

OP only needs to "double click on the cell and press enter" to get the formula evaluated. No need to update the formula. so I think setting calc mode to "auto" should be enough.  I noticed there is an "@" added in the excel, which is not in the original formula string written in Python. but I think that "@" is added by excel automatically and is harmless.
